# Hide Column Header in a pivot view of an Interactive Report (Oracle APEX 5.1)

Tags: oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Have a requirement wherein I should hide a column and also a pivot measure column heading in Oracle APEX 5.1.

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Can you be more specific with screenshot on what you really want to do? you can hide a column heading with &nbsp; on the heading or try to get the html element id or class attribute and the use css or javascript to hide or remove

Comment: The Screenshot is available in this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aiMV.png
I would need to remove or hide the highlighted parts of the image.

Answer (score 0):

- To remove the "edit pivot" button: 
  give an id to your IR report and then put the below code on 
  [image]
  **Execute when Page Loads** attribute:

$('#**your_report_id**_control_panel').hide()

- To remove the **sum.**  labbel :
  get each element id

  eg : $('#Element_id_1').html('');
- To remove the first row 
  get the first row id and then :

  $('#rowID').hide()

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you :) I was( able to hide the EDIT PIVOT section. But I was not able to find the Element ID and Row ID :(. Could you also please help me where I can find the Element ID and Row ID? Also these are to be written in the Execute when Page Loads right?

Comment: Used the CSS command :-    
table.a-IRR-table--pivot tr:nth-child(1) {
    display:none;
}; and I was able to hide it. Thank you Phanny